# Compute and plot tangent lines along a curve produced by polynomial regression using np.polyfit

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, regression, non-linear-regression

A curve is fitted to a data series using np.polyfit and evaluated with np.polyval to plot as:

[image]

How do I compute a tangent line at a point on the curve, and how to animate a series of tangent lines along the curve with x and y values in the series?

ps: Thanks to James Phillips' solution, a tangent line on the polynomial curve is plotted below:

[image: Tangent line on a polynomial curve]

```
x     y
0     21.05
1     21.21
2     20.76
3     20.34
4     20.27
5     20.78
6     20.60
7     20.55
8     19.95
9     19.23
10    19.64
11    19.92
12    19.91
13    19.56
14    19.39
15    19.31
16    19.35
17    18.97
18    18.69
19    19.00
20    19.15
21    19.08
22    18.97
23    19.26
24    19.52
25    19.56
26    19.28
27    19.47
28    19.85
29    19.77
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is example code using numpy's polyder() to automatically differentiate the polynomial, so that you don't need to manually calculate it - quite handy when changing the polynomial order during development. This draws the data, equation, and tangent line at a given "X" value, this should be enough to get you started. While I don't know your choice of animation technique, I personally save image sequences as PNG files, convert to GIF, and then use gifsicle for animations on my zunzun.com web site for creating 3D surface plot rotations.

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = numpy.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0])
yData = numpy.array([21.05, 21.21, 20.76, 20.34, 20.27, 20.78, 20.60, 20.55, 19.95, 19.23, 19.64, 19.92, 19.91, 19.56, 19.39, 19.31, 19.35, 18.97, 18.69, 19.00, 19.15, 19.08, 18.97, 19.26, 19.52, 19.56, 19.28, 19.47, 19.85, 19.77])

# polynomial curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, 3)


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    # polynomial derivative from numpy
    deriv = numpy.polyder(fittedParameters)

    # for plotting
    minX = min(xData)
    maxX = max(xData)

    # value of derivative (slope) at a specific X value, so
    # that a straight line tangent can be plotted at the point
    # you might place this code in a loop to animate
    pointVal = 15.0 # example X value
    y_value_at_point = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, pointVal)
    slope_at_point = numpy.polyval(deriv, pointVal)

    ylow = (minX - pointVal) * slope_at_point + y_value_at_point
    yhigh = (maxX - pointVal) * slope_at_point + y_value_at_point

    # now the tangent as a line plot
    axes.plot([minX, maxX], [ylow, yhigh])

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot


graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thanks James for the example codes and suggestion on GIF.. I can see how this may work in this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IWnf.gif :)

Comment: I have some matplotlib GIF animations here: http://zunzun.com/CommonProblems/ with the full source code here: https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/CommonProblems - the file to look at is named "generateOutput.py" which creates the animations.

Comment: That's super helpful :) thanks James! I also find this site very useful to produce GIF from images: http://gifmaker.me

Comment: Fantastic answer. Very helpful for understanding in general. I expanded on this for plotly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72802695/how-can-i-add-the-slope-of-a-specific-point-in-a-polynomial-line-in-plotly/72802696